# Trying to install Calendar.py

Tags: python, qpython

How can I get the library for calendar.py? I'm new to this.

I tried installing it and got the following error...

```
pip3 install calendar.py
Collecting calendar.py
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement calendar.py (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for calendar.py
```

Comment: try this `pip3 install calendar`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You don't install this module at all. It's part of the standard lib. Do you get an error when you try `import calendar`

Comment: I get the following...
>>> import calendar.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calendar.py'; 'calendar' is not a package
>>>

Comment: don't do ->  import calendar.py , do ->  import calendar

Comment: I'm trying to install calendar.py I used install command and also import and it doesn't work. What commands can I use? I'm new to python.